# Difference between componentWillMount and contructor in react?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, react-component

I checked out docs on `react`, I did not find any significant difference in between them. Can anybody help me to explain differences?

Comment: A simple google search can help you. Read life cycle methods in react JS

Comment: Yeah just found the discussions, sorry for asking duplicate one.